# Load application icon through resource

Tags: .net, resources, jscript.net

Here's what I've done:

I created a `resource.resx` file using my IDE (SharpDevelop) and added an `logo.ico` to it. The resource.resx file looks something like this:

```
<data name="logo" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
    <value>
        AAABAAEAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAA... (etc etc)
```

Then I used `ResGen.exe` to compile this `resource.resx` into a valid `resource.resources` file.

```
resgen.exe resource.resx resource.resources
```

Using the command line JScript.NET compiler I compiled everything and included my `resource.resources` which has my logo file.

```
jsc /res:resource.resources /out:app.exe /reference:UI.dll,Remote.dll app.cs
```

Now I want to access this logo file from withing my code, so I've got this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.Drawing.Icon icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("resource.resources.logo"));
```

However I get a runtime Exception for `GetManifestResourceStream` which is null.

I suppose this is a namespace issue so I tried accessing the resource file only with `GetManifestResourceStream("resource.resources")` but I get this other Exception:

`Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as a Icon.`

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is complaining about the file format, it doesn't recognize it as an icon.  I can't tell from your snippet, not enough of the base64 encoded value is visible.

I have to say, if this IDE is making you write code like this then it is *not* helping you.  Storing icons in the resources is utterly trivial in Visual Studio, there is no need to write any code at all.  The Express edition has the same price.